# Pronunciation of "McLeod"

Tags: pronunciation

How do we pronounce the Gaelic name *McLeod*?

Does any Gaelic name have a specific pronunciation? For the continental European it is a real nightmare.

Comment: yes, it is a "Highlander" hero, miklaud or something other?

Comment: "I'm Connor MacLeod of the Clan MacLeod.  I was born in the year 1518, and I will never die."

Comment: I believe sometimes, when they move to America, they use the spelling *McCloud*.  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065492/

Comment: I seem to recall visiting a Lake McLeod in my youth and the locals pronounced it "Mack-a-Lloyd"

Comment: The name "McLeod" is pronounced "Mac-li-odd", especially in North America.

Comment: In North America, the name *McLeod* is pronounced however the bearer of the name wants it to be pronounced. Sometimes it's /mək’liɑd/ and sometimes it's /mək’laʊd/.

Comment: I have frequently heard the name _MacLeod_ pronounced mə'klaʊd in the United States. There was a TV show in the 1970s (starring Dennis Weaver, who earlier played Chester Goode on _Gunmoke_) called _McCloud_ that likewise consistently used the pronunciation mə'klaʊd for the lead character's name (Sam McCloud). Both my father and my brother have _MacLeod_ as a middle name, and we pronounce it that way as well.

Comment: How did I miss this question? I was just asked (again) last week...

Comment: It is normally pronounced "muck loud" with the emphasis on the final syllable. It is worth pointing out, however, that the "leod" component originally comes from Norse "ljótr," meaning "ugly." The geneologists in my family tell me it was originally (in Norse) from a name meaning "ugly wolf" but I have no source for that at this time. However, the etymology of the name from Norse to Scottish Gaelic to English does give the name an unexpected pronunciation for the spelling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it helps, in the International Phonetic Alphabet, it’s/mək’laʊd/.

Answer (score 5):

The English pronounce McLeod "Mack Loud" with the emphasis on the second syllable.  If you make the effort to leave out the vowel in the first syllable entirely, that is good enough for most Scots, though the *c* should really sound like the *ch* in 'Bach'.

There are subleties beyond that, but probably not worth worrying about for your purposes. (All regions and languages have their own subtleties, and unless you can listen to a native, it is probably futile to worry about getting any name 'absolutely right' (let alone the differences in Scottish v Irish, Highland v Lowland, West Coast v East Coast... right down to those gravel-chewing barbarians at the bottom of the hill v the vowel-strangling snobs at the top.))

Comment: Why do you say the _c_ should really sound like the _ch_ in 'Bach'? "Mc" represents the Gaelic word "macc", which has a stop consonant.

Answer (score 2):

In Australian English 'McLeod' would be pronounced as 'McLoud'.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the Gaelic spelling is *Mac Leòid*, in Ireland that would be 'Mack Layoh-dge'.

Comment: It's also a Scottish name, MacLeòid, where it's [maxkˈlɔːtʲ], or approximately "Mach Lot".